# Can not parse json

Tags: javascript, json

Can not parse json using this

```
var res = eval('(' + response + ')');
```

The `response` contain `[{"total_sections":"3"}]` this value. But i couldn't take the value `total_sections`.

```
function changeSection() { 
   id = document.getElementById('layoutDropdown').value; 
   $.ajax({ type: "POST",
            url:'/manage',
            data: {id : id },
            success: function(response){ 
                  alert(response); 
                  var res = eval(response);
                  alert(res[0].total_sections);                     
            } 
    }); 
}
```

manage Layouts:

```
public function manageLayouts() { 
      $id = $_POST['id']; 
      $data = $this->managelayoutmodel->getSections($id);
      echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Comment: you should refrain from using the function eval(), read here why: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea  and here http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html

Comment: What is the result of `alert(typeof response);` before calling the eval?

Comment: guess, you just missed the `[0]` in your call? It should be accessable by `res[0].total_sections`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `response` is a `string` you can parse the json with `var res = eval(response);` (but it isn't nice), `var res = JSON.parse(response);` or if you use jQuery `var res = $.parseJSON(response)`. Otherwise if it is already an `object` you don't need to parse it, only set `var res = response;`.
Now you can get the total sections by calling `res[0].total_sections`, e.g. you can test it with `alert(res[0].total_sections);`.

Comment: @Anupama: You're welcome. It would be nice if you could [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) of all your questions.

Comment: @scessor stop pushing users into accepting answers when the problem isn't even solved...

Comment: @Christoph: 1.) I said "all of his questions" 2.) his comment pointed out that the problem was solved.

Answer (score 1):

You should always try to avoid using `eval`, it's evil!

You have 2 options:

If response is a string:

```
var res = JSON.parse(response);
```

or if it is already a JSON-Object (e.g. by setting the return type of you ajax call to json)

```
var res = response;
```

then you can access total sections by `res[0].total_sections`.

edit: your code has several problems:

add `var` before `id = document.getElementById('layoutDropdown').value;`. Sidenote: You are using jQuery, so this would be easier to access like this: `$("#layoutDropdown").val();`

do you run into the `alert(response)`? If not, your ajax call was not successfull. You should add an `error` Block to catch errors: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Do a console.log(response) and examine the result. Does it have the proper values you want it to have? (You also can check body of the ajax-call for that).

Most likely, neither the `eval(response)` nor the accessing `res[0].total_sections` are the parts where your trouble comes from.

Comment: I just tried using var res = JSON.parse(response); this.. But didnt get

Comment: post your whole code, so we can see, what you are trying to do.

Comment: <script>
    function changeSection() {        
        id = document.getElementById('layoutDropdown').value; 
        $.ajax({ 
            type: "POST",
            url:'/manage',          
            data: {id : id },
            success: function(response){
                alert(response);
                var res = eval(response);              
                alert(res[0].total_sections);
                
            }
    
        });
    }
</script>

Comment: public function manageLayouts() {
            $id = $_POST['id'];
            $data = $this->managelayoutmodel->getSections($id);           
            echo json_encode($data);
        }

Comment: @Anupama I edited my answer. Follow the steps and try if you can solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `JSON.parse(response)` in newer browsers. For older browsers use [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) and `JSON.parse(response)`

Comment: Tried in new browser. It still undefined